# Tracking down problems with text being ignored by ANTLR parser

Tags: java, antlr

I'm working on a parser that will split a string containing a person's full name into components (first, middle, last, title, suffix, ...). When I try a basic example "J. A. Doe" in ANTLRWorks, it matches the fname and lname rules, but ignores the "A.". How do I troubleshoot this type of problem?

[image]

#### Stripped-down grammar:

```
grammar PersonNamesMinimal;

fullname returns [Name name]
 : (directory_style[name] | standard[name] | proper_initials[name]);

fullname_only returns [Name name]: f=fullname EOF;

standard[Name name]
 : fname[name] ' ' (mname[name] ' ')* lname[name] ;

proper_initials[Name name]: a=INITIAL ' '? b=INITIAL lname[name];

sep: ',' | ', ' | ' ';
dir_sep: ',' | ', ' | ' , ';

directory_style[Name name]
 : lname[name] dir_sep fname[name] (' ' mname[name])*;

fname[Name name] : (f=NAME | f=INITIAL);

mname[Name name] : (m=NAME | m=INITIAL); // Weird bug when mname is "F."

lname[Name name] : a=single_lname (b='-' c=single_lname)?;
single_lname returns [String s]
 : (p=LNAME_PREFIX r=NAME)
 | r=NAME;
LNAME_PREFIX : (V O N | V A N ' ' D E R | V A N ' ' D E N | V A N | D E ' ' L A | D E | B I N) ' ';

O_APOS: ('O'|'o') '\'';
NAME: (O_APOS? LETTER LETTER+) | LETTER;
INITIAL: LETTER '.';

AND: ( ' '+ A N D ' '+ ) | (' '* '&' ' '*);
fragment WORD : LETTER+;
COMMA : ',';
//WS : ( '\t' | ' ' );

fragment DIGIT : '0' .. '9';
fragment LETTER : 'A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z';

//{{{ fragments for each letter of alphabet
fragment A : 'A' | 'a';
fragment B : 'B' | 'b';
fragment C : 'C' | 'c';
fragment D : 'D' | 'd';
fragment E : 'E' | 'e';
fragment F : 'F' | 'f';
fragment G : 'G' | 'g';
fragment H : 'H' | 'h';
fragment I : 'I' | 'i';
fragment J : 'J' | 'j';
fragment K : 'K' | 'k';
fragment L : 'L' | 'l';
fragment M : 'M' | 'm';
fragment N : 'N' | 'n';
fragment O : 'O' | 'o';
fragment P : 'P' | 'p';
fragment Q : 'Q' | 'q';
fragment R : 'R' | 'r';
fragment S : 'S' | 's';
fragment T : 'T' | 't';
fragment U : 'U' | 'u';
fragment V : 'V' | 'v';
fragment W : 'W' | 'w';
fragment X : 'X' | 'x';
fragment Y : 'Y' | 'y';
fragment Z : 'Z' | 'z';
//}}}
```

In creating this stripped-down version I discovered that removing either the `directory_style` rule or the `LNAME_PREFIX` rule causes the `mname` rule to work as expected, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Chances are that ANTLRWorks' interpreter is producing errors or warnings that you did not notice (also, the grammar might be okay, but the interpreter is causing problems: the interpreter is notoriously buggy!). It could therefor be possible that the parse tree you see is one where the parsing has (partially) failed. Could you post a grammar that I (or someone else) can run  without modifications?

Comment: @Bart - The bug is real in this case, I've verified it with unit tests against the generated parser. I looked on the Console and found `problem matching token at 1:5 MismatchedSetException(46!={78,110})`, but that doesn't get me much closer to finding the problem. I'll working on a stripped-down version of the grammar to post.

Comment: @Bart - I've posted a minimal version and discovered certain things that can be removed to fix the problem, but I'm still not sure what I'm actually doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with your parser rules, at least, not the problem you're facing at the moment... :). There's something going wrong in the lexer.

The initial `A.` from the input `"J. A. Doe"` is not being tokenized as an `INITIAL` but the lexer tries to create an `AND` token from it (note the space before the `'A'`!). You can see this by parsing the input `"J. X. Doe"` instead, with the even more trimmed grammar:

```java
grammar PersonNamesMinimal;

// just parse zero or more tokens (no matter what) and print their type and text
parse
  :  (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-25s \%s\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
  ;


LNAME_PREFIX : (V O N | V A N ' ' D E R | V A N ' ' D E N | V A N | D E ' ' L A | D E | B I N) ' ';
O_APOS       : ('O'|'o') '\'';
NAME         : (O_APOS? LETTER LETTER+) | LETTER;
INITIAL      : LETTER '.';
AND          : ( ' '+ A N D ' '+ ) | (' '* '&' ' '*);
COMMA        : ',';

fragment LETTER : 'A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z';

fragment A : 'A' | 'a';
fragment B : 'B' | 'b';
fragment C : 'C' | 'c';
fragment D : 'D' | 'd';
fragment E : 'E' | 'e';
fragment F : 'F' | 'f';
fragment G : 'G' | 'g';
fragment H : 'H' | 'h';
fragment I : 'I' | 'i';
fragment J : 'J' | 'j';
fragment K : 'K' | 'k';
fragment L : 'L' | 'l';
fragment M : 'M' | 'm';
fragment N : 'N' | 'n';
fragment O : 'O' | 'o';
fragment P : 'P' | 'p';
fragment Q : 'Q' | 'q';
fragment R : 'R' | 'r';
fragment S : 'S' | 's';
fragment T : 'T' | 't';
fragment U : 'U' | 'u';
fragment V : 'V' | 'v';
fragment W : 'W' | 'w';
fragment X : 'X' | 'x';
fragment Y : 'Y' | 'y';
fragment Z : 'Z' | 'z';

SPACE : ' ';
```

with the class:

```java
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    PersonNamesMinimalLexer lexer = new PersonNamesMinimalLexer(new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]));
    PersonNamesMinimalParser parser = new PersonNamesMinimalParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}
```

And then generate a lexer & parser, compile it all and then run Main with `"J. X. Doe"` as a command line parameter:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool PersonNamesMinimal.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main "J. X. Doe"
```

which prints the following on your console:

```
INITIAL                   J.
SPACE                      
INITIAL                   X.
SPACE                      
NAME                      Doe
```

(.ie. the expected output)

But now provide `"J. A. Doe"`:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main "J. A. Doe"
```

and the following output is produced:

```
line 1:4 mismatched character '.' expecting set null
INITIAL                   J.
SPACE                      
NAME                      Doe
```

If you now comment the rule `AND` in your lexer:

```java
...
INITIAL      : LETTER '.';
//AND          : ( ' '+ A N D ' '+ ) | (' '* '&' ' '*);
COMMA        : ',';
...
```

and test `"J. A. Doe"` again:

```
java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool PersonNamesMinimal.g 
javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main "J. A. Doe"
```

you will see this:

```
INITIAL                   J.
SPACE                      
INITIAL                   A.
SPACE                      
NAME                      Doe
```

(i.e. all goes well!)

---

How to fix it? If I were you, I'd first get the lexer much cleaner by removing all the literal spaces and put them on the `HIDDEN` channel so you won't have to account for them inside other parser- and lexer rules:

```
SPACE
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

That will at least solve this current problem you're facing. But there will probably be more...

---

### EDIT

> ***bemace wrote:***
>
> How would I modify the AND rule then so that it only matches whole words and not things like "stand"?

You don't need to do anything special for that to happen. As long as you have a rule that matches `"stand"`, or even `"andre"`, then they will not be tokenized as `AND`. In your case, `NAME` will match both of them, and because `NAME` matches more characters than `AND` for the input `"stand"` and `"andre"`, they will become `NAME` tokens.

This is how ANTLR's lexer work: the longest match is chosen, and if two rules match the same number of characters, the rule that is first defined gets precedence of the other rule.

A small test:

```java
grammar PersonNamesMinimal;

parse
  :  (t=. {System.out.printf("\%-25s \%s\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
  ;

AND
  :  A N D
  |  '&'
  ;

LNAME_PREFIX 
  :  V O N 
  |  V A N SPACES D E R 
  |  V A N SPACES D E N 
  |  V A N 
  |  D E SPACES L A 
  |  D E 
  |  B I N
  ;

INITIAL
  :  LETTER '.'
  ;

NAME
  :  (O '\'')? LETTER+ 
  ;

COMMA
  :  ','
  ;

SPACE 
  :  (' ' | '\t') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;

fragment LETTER : 'A' .. 'Z' | 'a' .. 'z';
fragment SPACES : (' ' | '\t')+;
fragment A : 'A' | 'a';
fragment B : 'B' | 'b';
fragment C : 'C' | 'c';
fragment D : 'D' | 'd';
fragment E : 'E' | 'e';
fragment F : 'F' | 'f';
fragment G : 'G' | 'g';
fragment H : 'H' | 'h';
fragment I : 'I' | 'i';
fragment J : 'J' | 'j';
fragment K : 'K' | 'k';
fragment L : 'L' | 'l';
fragment M : 'M' | 'm';
fragment N : 'N' | 'n';
fragment O : 'O' | 'o';
fragment P : 'P' | 'p';
fragment Q : 'Q' | 'q';
fragment R : 'R' | 'r';
fragment S : 'S' | 's';
fragment T : 'T' | 't';
fragment U : 'U' | 'u';
fragment V : 'V' | 'v';
fragment W : 'W' | 'w';
fragment X : 'X' | 'x';
fragment Y : 'Y' | 'y';
fragment Z : 'Z' | 'z';
```

And if you now parse the input:

```
"Andre and stand van     der"
```

you will see the expected tokens being created:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar Main "Andre and stand van     der"

NAME                      Andre
AND                       and
NAME                      stand
LNAME_PREFIX              van     der
```

Comment: How would I modify the `AND` rule then so that it only matches whole words and not things like "stand"?